# how to connect excel to MySQL using JSON

Tags: mysql, json, excel

I want to provide web service to my clients, allowing them to access the data from the excel files exported from MySQL database (Toad for MySQL). I want to use the JSON for connecting excel to MySQL. I googled it, and only found solutions using PHP or other languages.

Appreciated for any suggestions and hints.

Comment: JSON (JavaScript  Object Notation) is a data format, and not a programming language. You can't "connect" to MySQL using JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want to use the JSON for connecting excel to MySQL

Perhaps you mean JDBC or ODBC? If you did mean JSON, then JSON is a data format, not a "connection" utility.

> I want to provide web service to my clients, allowing them to access the data from the excel files exported from MySQL database

The web service should expose the database, not an excel file.

> only found solutions using PHP or other languages

With regards to *other languages* - Yes, there are many ways to create a web service, PHP being one of those. Again, if you did mean JSON, you can use whatever technology you are comfortable that includes a JSON library and a MySQL driver.

To my knowledge there is no library for direct translation from JSON to SQL, though.